# Website login in c# WP8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Im trying to develop an app for this webpage so the users will be able to log in and see their details (scedule and such).

http://www.lectio.dk/lectio/317/default.aspx

However I'm quite new at working with getting data from the web, and this page seems quite hard to get any data from (dont judge me :D).

The page uses gzip
The page has some hidden fields with generated id's which needs to me submitted with username and password
The page complains about missing per-session cookies

Here's what my code looks like right now:

First my Mywebclient class:

```
public class MyWebClient : SharpGIS.GZipWebClient
{
    Uri _responseUri;
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    public MyWebClient()
    {
        this.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    public MyWebClient(CookieContainer cookieContainer)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    }
    public Uri ResponseUri
    {
        get { return _responseUri; }
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result);
        _responseUri = response.ResponseUri;
        return response;
    }
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request == null) return base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}`
```

Secondly the code which calls the loading

```
string postdata = "m$Content$password2=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("PASSWORD") + "m$Content$username2=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("USERNAME");
navigatePostRequestBrowser(new Uri("https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/317/login.aspx"), postdata);
```

And finally the loading

```
protected void navigatePostRequestBrowser(Uri url, string postdata)
{
    MyWebClient webClient = new MyWebClient();
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(proxy_UploadStringCompleted);
    webClient.UploadStringAsync(url , "POST", postdata);
}
```

My UploadStringCompleted looks like this:

```
private void proxy_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var response = e.Result;
}
```

I have no idea if this i even nearly correct, since i've tried out several solutions found everywhere on the internet.

Please help me - I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a static hidden webbrowser instead of a webclient.